# Как изменить начальное положение экрана?

Tags: javascript, css3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить начальное положение экрана пользователя при помощи css/js. Необходимо сделать так, что при входе на сайт, пользователь попадал в самый низ страницы, а не в вверх как стоит по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Можно также без JavaScript. На странице в самом конце ставите элемент `<a id="bottom">`, а дальше линк на страницу не `example.html`, а `example.html#bottom`.

Comment: Второй вариант мне не подходит, а первый не работает. Возможно это связано с тем что у меня на body установлен `overflow: hidden;`?

Comment: Хотя нет, убрал `overflow: hidden` и все равно не сработало.

Comment: Код я вам дал правильный: можете открыть (на этой же странице) консоль и скопировать код. Увидите, страница передвинется вверх. Можете в свой вопрос добавить ваш код, возможно кто-нибудь найдет, где ошибка.

Comment: Уже разобрался. Спасибо за то, что направили в нужном направлении.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
Помог этот код `$("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#bottom")[0].offsetTop }, 10);`, где `#bottom` - id html элемента, который я расположил внизу кода.